# EnumProcesses()

Tags: visual-c++

I wrote a basic code (by VC++) to retrieve the list of processes by EnumProcesses() in Psapi. I open VS2012 in admin mode. During debugging the code succesfully retrieves all the process handles. As I build the process it couldn't get process handles as a stand-alone application; most process handles return NULL values. I tried to set the "UAC execution level" in linker to requireAdministrator; but nothing changes. Any recommendations?

```
DWORD proc_id[1024];    // array for process id's
DWORD ret_bytes;        // number of bytes returned from EnumProcesses()
FILE *proc_file;        // to store the process list

// Get list of process id's
if ( !EnumProcesses( proc_id, sizeof(proc_id), &ret_bytes ) )
{
    printf("Can not execute EnumProcesses()...\n");
    system("pause");
    return;
}
printf("Retriving process id list...\n");
// Calculate how many process identifiers were returned.
DWORD number_of_proc;   // number of processes
number_of_proc = ret_bytes / sizeof(DWORD);
printf("%u working processes found...\n",number_of_proc);

// Read all the process' names

proc_file=fopen("process.txt","w");
for (unsigned int i=0;i<number_of_proc;i++)
{
    if (proc_id[i]!=0) // if the id is not empty
    {
        TCHAR proc_name[MAX_PATH] = TEXT("<unknown>"); // array for storing name of process
        TCHAR file_name[MAX_PATH] = TEXT("<unknown>"); // array for executable of process
        HANDLE proc_handle = OpenProcess(PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS , false, proc_id[i]);   // open the process
        if(proc_handle==NULL) fprintf(proc_file,"%3u - NULL HANDLE (PID: %u) err %u\n\n",i,proc_id[i],GetLastError());
        HMODULE hMod;
        DWORD cbNeeded;
        if(EnumProcessModulesEx( proc_handle, &hMod, sizeof(HMODULE),&cbNeeded,LIST_MODULES_ALL))
        {
            GetModuleBaseName( proc_handle, hMod, proc_name,sizeof(proc_name)/sizeof(TCHAR) ); // Get the name of the process
            /*_tprintf( TEXT("%3u - %s  (PID: %u)\n"),i, proc_name,proc_id[i] );*/
            fprintf(proc_file,("%3u - %s  (PID: %u)\n"),i, proc_name,proc_id[i]);
            //GetProcessImageFileName(proc_handle,file_name,sizeof(file_name)/sizeof(TCHAR));
            DWORD size=sizeof(file_name)/sizeof(TCHAR);
            QueryFullProcessImageName(proc_handle,0,file_name,&size);   // Get the name of the image base file
            //_tprintf( TEXT("%s\n"),file_name );
            fprintf(proc_file,("\t%s\n"),file_name);
        }
        else
            if(proc_handle!=NULL)
                fprintf(proc_file,"%3u - EnumProcessModules() not working... (PID: %u) err %u\n",i,proc_id[i],GetLastError());
        //QueryFullProcessImageName(proc_handle,1,proc_name,sizeof(proc_name)/sizeof(TCHAR));
        //GetProcessImageFileName(proc_handle,proc_name,sizeof(proc_name)/sizeof(TCHAR));


    }
}
fclose(proc_file);
```

Comment: Please show your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS when you don't have the permission, invoke your SeDebugPrivilege privilege
Reference
[How To Use the SeDebugPrivilege to Acquire Any Process Handle](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/185215)

Comment: Thanks for example. AdjustTokenPrivileges does not modify the privilege. Any recommendations?

Comment: AdjustTokenPrivileges can only enable privileges that are disabled, it cannot add privileges that are not included the user token. If you don't have the privilege to begin with, ask the user to run your program under an account that does have the privilege.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to recommendations I was able to sort the problem. Below is the working code for info

```
DWORD proc_id[1024];    // array for process id's
DWORD ret_bytes;        // number of bytes returned from EnumProcesses()
FILE *proc_file;        // to store the process list
HANDLE hProcess;        // handle for current process
HANDLE hToken;          // handle for token result
LUID Luid;              // local unique identifier
TOKEN_PRIVILEGES TP;    // token priviliges
TOKEN_PRIVILEGES TPprev;
DWORD cbprev;


hProcess = GetCurrentProcess();  // Get handle for current process
DWORD lResult = OpenProcessToken(hProcess, TOKEN_ADJUST_PRIVILEGES | TOKEN_QUERY , &hToken); // Open process token for current process
if (lResult==0){
    printf("Cannot open process token: %x\n",lResult);
    system("pause");
    return;}
else{
    printf("Open process token: %x\n",hToken);
}

// Grab the LUID for the request privilege.
lResult = LookupPrivilegeValue(NULL, SE_DEBUG_NAME, &Luid);
if (lResult==0){
    printf("Cannot open look up priv. value: %x\n",lResult);
    system("pause");
    return;}
else{
    printf("Priv. look up succesfull: %x\n",Luid);
}

cbprev=sizeof(TP);
TP.PrivilegeCount=1;
TP.Privileges[0].Luid = Luid;
TP.Privileges[0].Attributes = 0;
lResult = AdjustTokenPrivileges(hToken, FALSE, &TP, sizeof(TP), &TPprev, &cbprev );
if (lResult==0){
    printf("Cannot retrieve privilege: %x (error:%u)\n",lResult,GetLastError());
    system("pause");
    return;}
else{
    printf("Privilege retrieved succesfully\n");
}
// Adjust the token privilege
TPprev.PrivilegeCount=1;
TPprev.Privileges[0].Luid=Luid;
TPprev.Privileges[0].Attributes=2;  //SE_PRIVILEGE_ENABLED
lResult = AdjustTokenPrivileges(hToken, FALSE, &TPprev, sizeof(TP), &TP, &cbprev);
if (lResult==0){
    printf("Cannot adjust privilege: %x (error:%u)\n",lResult,GetLastError());
    system("pause");
    return;}
else{
    printf("Privilege adjusted succesfully\n");
}
// Get list of process id's
if ( !EnumProcesses( proc_id, sizeof(proc_id), &ret_bytes ) )
{
    printf("Can not execute EnumProcesses()...\n");
    system("pause");
    return;
}
printf("Retriving process id list...\n");
// Calculate how many process identifiers were returned.
DWORD number_of_proc;   // number of processes
number_of_proc = ret_bytes / sizeof(DWORD);
printf("%u working processes found...\n",number_of_proc);

// Read all the process' names

proc_file=fopen("process.txt","w");
for (unsigned int i=0;i<number_of_proc;i++)
{
    if (proc_id[i]!=0) // if the id is not empty
    {
        TCHAR proc_name[MAX_PATH] = TEXT("<unknown>"); // array for storing name of process
        TCHAR file_name[MAX_PATH] = TEXT("<unknown>"); // array for executable of process
        HANDLE proc_handle = OpenProcess(PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS , false, proc_id[i]);   // open the process
        if(proc_handle==NULL) fprintf(proc_file,"%3u - NULL HANDLE (PID: %u) err %u\n\n",i,proc_id[i],GetLastError());
        HMODULE hMod;
        DWORD cbNeeded;
        if(EnumProcessModulesEx( proc_handle, &hMod, sizeof(HMODULE),&cbNeeded,LIST_MODULES_ALL))
        {
            GetModuleBaseName( proc_handle, hMod, proc_name,sizeof(proc_name)/sizeof(TCHAR) ); // Get the name of the process
            fprintf(proc_file,("%3u - %s  (PID: %u)\n"),i, proc_name,proc_id[i]);
            DWORD size=sizeof(file_name)/sizeof(TCHAR);
            QueryFullProcessImageName(proc_handle,0,file_name,&size);   // Get the name of the image base file
            fprintf(proc_file,("\t%s\n"),file_name);
        }
        else
            if(proc_handle!=NULL)
                fprintf(proc_file,"%3u - EnumProcessModules() not working... (PID: %u) err %u\n",i,proc_id[i],GetLastError());


    }
}
fclose(proc_file);
```